# Select distinct from a column using RFC Table Options Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, saprfc

How to query distinct values from a column using rfc table options in copy activity azure data factory?

I had a SAP Table connector, and i want to query a copy activity, for example in the table above, i want to use the RFC Table options to query distinct Dates from the table.

| DATE | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 20220304 | A |
| 20230304 | B |

[image]

unfortunately I found little information and documentation from MS that imply how to do this type of query using the available options.